# kendo ui jquery toolbar button badge not working

Tags: jquery, button, kendo-ui, toolbar, badge

Is this limitation documented or why are badges not rendered on a button(group) in toolbar widget?

demo:
[enter link description here](https://dojo.telerik.com/enOSuxEw)

Comment: Please elaborate better your issue.

Comment: If you follow attached linked you will see that badges are not working on buttons in a toolbar widget.

Comment: What do you mean by *working* ? I opened the link, the badges are there but you didn't specified what behaviour they should have.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should present demo better. In demo you see TWO cases: stand-alone button group and button group in a toolbar widget. First one (stand-alone) is on top and you can see the badges. Second one (toolbar) is bottom and you don't see badges. Or? I think badges should be rendered on toolbar items as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Badges are not supported out of the box on buttons or button groups in a toolbar widget. I think this was overlooked by kendo team as I can't see any reason why toolbar buttons should behave differently. If defined, they are simply ignored. I was able to make rather simple work around to make my own toolbar button badge functionality.